# How to track modifier keys using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

My requirement is just easy: user press Ctrl key some notification appear on my page, and when released the notifications just disappear, so i need to track modifier keys such as Ctrl. Unfortunately i google and didn't find any clues, some famous keyboard libs such as [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) and `keymaster` seem also does not cover this topic.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that Mousetrap does cover modifier usage. I'm not sure if they covered it when this was posted, but it's on their front page now. 

Do something like: 
    Mousetrap.bind('command+shift+k', function(e) {
        /*do things*/
    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can just use the keydown and keyup event handlers and you will see the Ctrl key go down and up.  If you want to keep track of whether it's down or up, then just set a global flag when it goes down and clear the flag when it goes up.

Example code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 17) {
        $("#result").append("ctrl key pressed<br>");
    }
});
```

JQuery doc on e.which: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mezwF/

Comment: I liked this (and used it) because its makes detecting key combinations like ctrl+shft+alt really easy to do.

Answer (score 9):

Modifier keys trigger `keydown` (but not `keypress`). Then you can simply check the flags defined on the event object. `shiftKey`, `altKey`, `ctrlKey`, `metaKey`, etc.

A full list is here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
var ctrlKey = false;
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 17) {
        ctrlKey = true;
    }
};
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 17) {
        ctrlKey = false;
    }
};
function notify() {
    if(ctrlKey) {
        $('#notification').show();
    } else {
        $('#notification').hide();
    }
}
function main() {
    var _inter = setInterval(notify, 100);
}

main();
```

Comment: Why use a timer?  Why not just hide/down the notification when the key goes down/up.  You have an event that changes the state.  You don't need to poll the state.